# Why unable to found Makefile still they are present in directory using 'make' command?

Tags: macos, apache, unix, makefile

over Macbook terminal, i am installing apache httpd, so it docs say to run make command so as to run Makefiles..Although the apache directory has makefile,still it didnt find it
Before this i went to httpd directory and run ./configure but error appears that C compiler cannot create executable files
[image][image]

Comment: Please add what is in `config.log`

Comment: Your attempt at running `configure` failed. You need to figure out why it failed. The way to run `make` on a specific makefile is `make -f <file>` not `make <file>` also.

Comment: @Etan i tried that make -f option also still it doesn't work..this is frustrating..can u please provide detail guide on this

Comment: Running `./configure` **failed**. You need to get that working before running `make` will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check what is on `line 15` of yout GNUmakefile.

Seems you are using something  [like this](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/branches/2.4.x/NWGNUmakefile)

And line 15 expect that  `APR_WORK` defined in your `env` otherwise  `APR_WORK` will be set to your current directory `$PWD`

Also usually you have to run `./configure` before `make`

Comment: i did run the ./configure but it gives error C compiler cannot create executables..

Comment: @koolomi, please update your question, with errors and all things like that you did.

Comment: here is the same written on line 15 of GNUmakefile - error (APR_WORK does not point to a valid APR source tree)

Comment: Makefile is trying to find "$(APR_WORK)/include/apr_version.h" . Try to find it. and set appropriate APR_WORK with `export APR_WORK=$GOOD_PATH`

Comment: Found the apr_version.h and updated Path for APR_WORK still  same error comes that error (APR_WORK does not point to a valid APR source tree)

Comment: can u help me solve ./configure error that C compiler cannot create executable files

Comment: @koolomi Please add source of `config.log`